# What are the limitations on the flat prior in the BAT framework?

Tags: bayesian, prior

By default, the BAT framework sets the flat priors on the parameter. My question is: how in this case allowed range for a parameter of the flat function is estimated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By BAT you mean https://bat.mpp.mpg.de?

In any case, after setting your priors (lets say you choose flat priors) you have to determine the posterior distribution for your parameters (thats the probability of your model given the data) by folding with the likelihood function (the probability of the data given your model).  This is done using Bayes theorem.

If your likelihood is informative, when you calculate the posterior distribution you would will find that is only relevant in some region(s) of your parameter space.  You can do then some point estimate like finding the maximum of the posterior (aka your best guess) and some credible intervals (eg regions centered around the maximum and containing 95% probability)